# PhpStorm 2016 change position of the {} on the end of functions, loops, etc

Tags: php, visual-studio, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 2016. I've come from the Visual Studio C# world, and I've became used to the `{}`'s like this:

```
function foo()
{
   code
}
```

but in the PhpStorm by default, its like this:

```
function foo() {
    code
}
```

Is there a configuration on PhpStorm so that I can get my `{}`'s like my first example? (the Visual Studio C# one)

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/code-style.html

Answer (score 2):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style`
2. `PHP | Wrapping & Braces`
3. `Braces placement -> In function declaration = Next line`

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/code-style-php.html#d532466e260

[image]